# Why does GCC look at private constructors when matching functions?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm very busy write now debugging some code, so I can't cookup a complete example, but this basically describes my problem

```
class Base{};
class MyX:public Base
{
  ...
};
class Derived:Base
{
  ...
};
template<class X>
class MyClass:Derived
{
private:
   MyClass(const MyClass& )
     :x()
   {}
public:
   MyClass(const X& value)
    :x(value)
   {}
};

....
MyX      x;
MyClass<MyX>(x);
```

This gives me an error like this:

```
error: there are two possible constrcutors MyClass<X>(const MyClass<X>&) and MyClass<X>(const X&)
```

Comment: Does MyX derive from MyClass?

Comment: Not directly but as my update shows they do share an ancestor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyClass<MyX>(x);
```

is parsed as

```
MyClass<MyX> x;
```

But `MyClass<MyX>` does not have a default constructor. Try giving it a name:

```
MyClass<MyX> p(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to give us a more complete code example. For instance, in constructor MyClass(const X&), you are initializing "x" with "x"?

```
MyClass(const& X value)
  :x(x)
```

Comment: that was a typo, should've been value